# How to prove $\mu(E)\neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

This picture is from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, page 118.

In 6.3 Lemma, $\left|\mu\right|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

In the last line but two, $\left|\mu(A)\right|\gt t/\pi\gt 1$ shows $\mu(E)\neq 0$, but how to prove it?

Comment: Please do not use inline images to relay the bulk of your question. Screen readers and search engines cannot parse images.

Comment: You mean in theorem 2.4

Comment: Formulating and writing down your own question instead of posting a picture of it might give you good insights...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu(E)$ may well be zero in the proof of Rudin. The actual value is irrelevant, only the fact that it contains a subset $A$ and its complement $B$  which both have measures of absolute values at least 1.

Comment: How can $E$ have measure zero?

Comment: $\mu$ is a complex (signed) measure. If $E=X=[-1,1]$ with $d\mu = {\rm sign}(x) dx$ then $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: its variation is positive?

Comment: yes, $|\mu|(E)=2$